# Kafka uneven partitions assignment

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a changelog topic with 100 partitions. I am running 3 application with same application-id. When all 3 apps are running, partition assignment is very uneven. Instead of 33-33-34 (or nearby same) partitions, partition assignment looks like 43-43-14. What can be the reason behind the same?

I have checked that there is no custom partition assignor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason. 1 of the systems had higher number of stream threads configured.